# Celery prefork memory leak

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

We are running Celery with Django using the following command:
python manage.py celery worker -Q some_queue -l INFO -n some_worker —concurrency=1

The flow is as such - (assume `CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1`):
1. When running celery, a master process is spawned (about 60MB RAM)
2. Child process is immediately forked from it (also 60MB)
3. Master process pulls a task from the queue and hands it over to the child
3. The child process finishes handling a task and is terminated by the master process and it's memory is freed
4. Master process now pulls another task from the queue and it's memory increases to 72MB
5. Child process is forked from the master queue (also 72MB)

...and so on and so forth.

So in fact, the master process is never restarted, only the children do. But every message it takes increases it's memory usage and thus after a while we run out of memory.

We have tried the following settings to no avail:

```
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1

CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1

-Ofair
```

Comment: any updates on this?